# Solving differential equation with trigonometric and exponential functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve $e^x \sin(x) + e^y \cos(y) \cdot y' =0$.

Trying to solve it via separation of variables or treating it as an exact differential equation, I end up solving

$\frac{1}{2} (e^x (\cos x-\sin x) + e^y (\sin y+\cos y) + C = 0$ for $y(x)$ ($C$ being a constant).

I tried different things in order to come closer to a solution (or showing that there is none), but nothing worked (mathematica for example says it cannot be solved). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: An equation defining the function implicitly can perfectly be the way to present the solution of a differential equation.

Comment: no Chance to find an explicit solution

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Can I somehow proof this?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is given by $$e^y(\cos(y)+\sin(y))=e^x(\cos(x)-\sin(x))+C$$

Comment: then try it, it is wasting time